# sorting dictionary with list value (python)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
dict={"a":[1,2,3,12],"b":[5,6,7,8],"c":[9,10,11,4]}
```

This is my dictionary I want to sort `dict` by the last index of each value list...is it possible?
I mean that I want to sort `dict` by this number 4,8,12 and print it.
so output will be:

```
{'a': [9, 10, 11, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'c': [1,2,3,12]}
```

Comment: `dict`s are by definition _unordered_

Comment: You can rely on dict ordering by insertion in 3.7+ but [there's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876). Consider showing an attempt or more context to improve the quality of answers you receive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not name a Python variable `dict`. I will call the dict `d` instead.

```py
$ python
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:42:20)
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = {"a":[1,2,3,12],"b":[5,6,7,8],"c":[9,10,11,4]}
```

This yields a sorted list of the dict items:

```py
>>> sorted(list(d.items()), key=lambda x: x[1][3])
[('c', [9, 10, 11, 4]), ('b', [5, 6, 7, 8]), ('a', [1, 2, 3, 12])]
```

Now we can get the sorted dict:

```py
>>> dict(sorted(list(d.items()), key=lambda x: x[1][3]))
{'c': [9, 10, 11, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'a': [1, 2, 3, 12]}
```